# Javascript: Moving an image created programmatically not working

Tags: javascript, css, image, position, move

I am learning `javascript` and I came to a point where I created an image like this:

```
function placeThePawn(){
base_image = new Image();
base_image.src = 'pawns/pawn_red.png';
base_image.onload = function(){
    ctx.drawImage(base_image, 50, 50 , 32 , 32);
}
}
```

[I searched and read few tutorial to learn how to move the pawn]

Now I made a function to move the pawn (image) like this:

```
function moveThePawn() {
base_image.style.left = parseInt(base_image.style.left) + 100 + 'px';
}
```

Somehow it doesn't seem to work.

I want to know how can I implement this (move the pawn) **and** would also want to know why this is not working!

Comment: Could you provide a jsfiddle with your code ?

Comment: @DemeterDimitri not sure what does that mean, 'jsfiddle'? u mean the entile js file?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/ , I think you need to redraw the canvas(ctx). Because `base_image` is not in canvas, is just a image object(element).

Comment: @DemeterDimitri Don't advice jsfiddle. Advice code snippets. Use tools from Stack Overflow if you can.

Comment: @randy if I use var, the variable will be local and I wont be able to use it in other function at all.

Comment: @SrujanBarai There is a button in the question editor with `<>` tags on it. Click that, make an example using that editor. Then, we can run it and see what happens.

Comment: @DemeterDimitri Well I already have quite a few file with scripts, style, node and html. Adding them all to jsfiddle will be difficult.

Comment: @randy  You can check the code here: https://github.com/srujan7/Masti---The-life-simulation-game I have it there. In the latest code, I have added the above functions in the board.js file.

Comment: @SrujanBarai I think you'll like my second example, that gives you some more control over the object. Its the way I like to do things; powerfull but readable.

Answer (score 1):

You will have to call the function `movethePawn();` 
Have this in your `<body onkeyup="moveSelection(event)">`

and this in your script

```
function moveSelection(event) {                    
                if(event.keyCode === 37) {
                    movethePawn();
         }
       }
```

EDIT 1 :

You may need to construct this image as an element in your DOM and have that element with document.getElementbyId and move it left. It won't work directly with an Image object

Comment: I am already calling that function on button click. And its getting called. I checked with the log.

Comment: Please look at Edit 1

Answer (score 1):

This code creates your pawn, and moves it after two seconds using only your functions (and a `clearRect` to remove the old icon)

```js
var base_image;

var c = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
var ctx = c.getContext("2d");

function placeThePawn(){
  base_image = new Image();
  base_image.src = 'http://placehold.it/200x200';
  base_image.onload = function(){
    ctx.drawImage(base_image, 50, 50 , 32 , 32);
  }
}

function moveThePawn() {
  ctx.clearRect(0,0,200,100);
    ctx.drawImage(base_image, 150, 50 , 32 , 32);
}

placeThePawn();

setTimeout(moveThePawn, 2000);
```

```html
<canvas id="myCanvas" width="200" height="100" style="border:1px solid #000000;">
</canvas>
```

This is a better example of how to do this:

```js
var base_image;

var c = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
var ctx = c.getContext("2d");

var clearMyCanvas = function(){ctx.clearRect(0,0,1000,1000)};

var pawn = {
  x:50,
  y:50,
  h:32,
  w:32,
  render: function placeThePawn(){
    base_image = new Image();
    base_image.src = 'http://placehold.it/200x200';
    base_image.onload = function(){
      ctx.drawImage(base_image, pawn.x, pawn.y , pawn.w , pawn.h);
    }
  }
}


pawn.render();

// redraw all the things you want on your next screen here.
setTimeout(function(){
  // clear canvas
  clearMyCanvas();
  // perform logics
  pawn.x += 100; 
  // redraw
  pawn.render()
}, 2000);
```

```html
<canvas id="myCanvas" width="200" height="100" style="border:1px solid #000000;">
</canvas>
```

Comment: Thank you for your efforts but I guess this wont really help in my case. I wanted to move my pawn from one place to another (smooth move). Clearing the canvas every time and redrawing it is not the good idea I guess.

Comment: @SrujanBarai this is the way Games work. You keep state in an object and Draw states. Never do it the other way around. If you Let code depend on the current drawings, it will never be good code.

Comment: Okay, what else I was thinking was, letting my board as it is (as it is static) and using another JavaScript file to draw the pawns on it, as another layer. Though I dont know if that is even possible. Would want to give it a try.

Comment: Sure it is. Make Every pawn object a file, Make the rendering another file. Import in the Right order and call rendering for Every object Every Move.

Comment: That doesn't sound at all easy to me but would try. ty for atleast guiding.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are mixing up the html5 canvas element (as seen in `ctx.drawImage(base_image, 50, 50 , 32 , 32);`) with simple html and css.

this line:  `base_image.style.left = parseInt(base_image.style.left) + 100 + 'px';` is attempting to change the css style property of an element saved in a variable called `base_image`. But there is no such element.

What you need to change is not the style of `base_image`, but the canvas context `ctx` where `base_image` has been drawn.

```
function moveThePawn() {
ctx.drawImage(base_image, 50, 50 , 32 , (32+100));//add the 100 pixels to the canvas rendering of the image
}
```

Comment: Great! but it is not moving the object, its redrawing it. So now I have two pawns...

Comment: I can't help you more because I don't know if all your chess pieces are drawn on a single canvas, or if you have one canvas per piece. In the first case, the answer from @randy will be useful, in the second, it's more complicated. You need to store each of the moves you make so that you can undo them later.